# Calling redirect_to and seemingly nothing new is rendered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Calling `redirect_to controller: 'messages', action: 'index'` in one controller.

With index being defined in the messages controller as such:

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => Message.all }
    format.html { }
  end
end
```

However nothing seems to be redirected at the browser level, i.e. the /messages is not displayed.

Thoughts?

From the log:

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-21 21:15:31 -0500
Processing by UsersController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"name"=>"testsg", "phone_number"=>"8593385412"}
  [1m[36m (4.0ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35mUser Exists (15.6ms)[0m  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."handle" = 'testsg' LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mUser Exists (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."phone_number" = '18593385412' LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (15.6ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "handle", "phone_number", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Mon, 22 Dec 2014 02:15:31 UTC +00:00], ["handle", "testsg"], ["phone_number", "18593385412"], ["updated_at", Mon, 22 Dec 2014 02:15:31 UTC +00:00]]
  [1m[36m (31.3ms)[0m  [1mCOMMIT[0m
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/messages
Completed 302 Found in 120ms (ActiveRecord: 68.0ms)
```

rest of controller code:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :subscribe, :only => :index

  # put your own credentials here
  account_sid = 'XXXXXXXXXX'
  auth_token = 'XXXXXXXXXX'

  # set up a client to talk to the Twilio REST API
  @@client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token

  def index
    respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render :json => Message.all }
        format.html { }
    end
  end

  def create
    params.has_key?(:Body) ? message = params[:Body] : message = params[:message]

    @@client.messages.create(
      from: 'XXXXXXXXXX',
      to: 'XXXXXXXXXX',
      body: "#{current_user.handle}: #{message}"
    )

    render :json => $pubnub.publish(
        :channel => 'pubnub_chat',
        :callback => lambda {|x|},
        :message => {
            #:user_id => current_user.id,
            :user_id => current_user.id,
            :message => "#{message}"
        }
    )
  end

  private

  def subscribe
    puts 'subscribing...'

    $pubnub.subscribe(
        :channel => 'pubnub_chat',
        :callback => $callback
    ) unless $pubnub.subscription_running?
  end
end
```

Where the redirect is coming from:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(handle: params['name'], phone_number: params['phone_number'])
  if @user.save
      #render :json => [ @photo.to_jq_upload].to_json
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      redirect_to controller: 'messages', action: 'index'
  else 
      #render :json => [{ :error => "An error was encountered while processing your photos. Please try again." }], :status => 304
  end
end
```

Comment: Post the rails log and the other controller source code.

Comment: @MaurícioLinhares posted! Thoughts?

Comment: The logs show the redirect clearly happened, isn't there another request just after that?

Comment: What URL do you see at the browser after creating the User?

Comment: @MaurícioLinhares agreed, and I guess maybe not, but I'm guessing maybe there should? (Also, just posted the code from which the redirect is coming!)

Comment: @DarioBarrionuevo 'http://localhost:3000/'

Comment: Just to be sure, can you explicitly set the request format in the user's form? Something like form_for @user, format: 'html' do |f|

Comment: As in the form that calls user#create? @DarioBarrionuevo

Comment: Yes, because the request is being sent as */* (UsersController#create as */*), no specific format, and maybe that could be confusing the controller.

Comment: Will do! Also, so I set the redirect_to format explicitly to 'json' and still nothing?

Comment: Could this possibly be a POST and GET issue? Maybe in your routes you need to add POST to your `messages#index` action.

Answer (score 0):

> You have used redirect_to action: "course_page1", format: "html" and
>   return which is not right. Redirection will work fine if it was an
>   html request but not ajax. So if you want to redirect despite the fact
>   that the request was an ajax, use may something like this
>
> format.js { render :js => "window.location.href =
>   '#{course_page_path}'" }

[Rails console shows view is rendered, but doesn't render in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26425083/rails-console-shows-view-is-rendered-but-doesnt-render-in-browser/26425405#26425405)